# Differentiated TOC/body section names in reledpar

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, reledmac, reledpar

In a reledpar project I'd like for some sections to appear in the TOC with different names than how they appear in the body. Normally this is straightforward: `\section[name in TOC]{name in body}`. However, this generates an error if attempted within reledpar (`Argument of \ttl@straight@i has an extra }`) or reledmac (`Incomplete \iffalse`).

Is there a way to make this sectioning feature work in reledpar? An alternate solution through titlesec and titletoc may be possible, but it would be more complex.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac, reledpar}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}
      \beginnumbering
      %% the line below gives an error `Argument of \ttl@straight@i has an extra }`
      %% (error even if the right side too has differentiated TOC and body section names to match these)
      %\pstart[\section[Left section in TOC]{Left section in body}]
      \pstart[\section{Left section}]
        Left paragraph.
      \pend
      \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
      \beginnumbering
      \pstart[\section{Right section}]
        Right paragraph.
      \pend
      \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}
  \end{pages}
  \Pages

  %\beginnumbering
  %% the line below gives an error `Incomplete \iffalse`
  %  \pstart[\section[Reledmac section in TOC]{Reledmac section in body}]
  %    A reledmac paragraph.
  %  \pend
  %\endnumbering

  % no error outside of reledpar and reledmac
  \section[Non-reledpar section in TOC]{Non-reledpar section in body}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `titlesec`, `titletoc` and `tocloft`, in one file? That's a pretty combination ;-)

Comment: Oops! `tocloft` must have stuck when copied from somewhere else. I was experimenting with the other two, but they're not necessary either for this MWE, so I've removed them. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a problem of expansion. I have notime now to understand the problem in reledmac code (you could open an issue), but a `\unexpanded` work around.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{reledmac, reledpar}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
  \beginnumbering
   \pstart[\unexpanded{\section[reledmac section in toc]{reledmac section in body}}]
      a reledmac paragraph.
    \pend
  \endnumbering

  % no error outside of reledpar and reledmac
  \section[Non-reledpar section in TOC]{Non-reledpar section in body}
\end{document}
```